# How do I make a compositor filter effect affect only a specific part of the render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting

So, this is my node setup and as you can see the sunbeams affect the entire image.

[image]

However, I only want it to emit out of the doorway. So I created a mask for that and plugged it into the factor input.

[image]

But the output isn't exactly accurate.

[image]

So, how do I solve this?

Comment: You might start by centering the sun beams on the door a bit better...there isn't much of the effect by the door anyway.

Comment: @JakeD alright, how do I do that?

Comment: I think the mask is limiting the addition to the doorway itself and not anywhere outside it. Can you show the mask?

Comment: @RonProctor I just added the mask above, have a look

Comment: I see the mask now. You could use the mask to darken the rest of the picture, pass it through the sunbeam node, then add the result to the base picture.

Comment: @RonProctor Thanks! That worked like a charm. By the way, is there any way the sunbeam and the light source can have the same color? as it is now, the light is yellow/orange colored whereas the sunbeam is white colored.

Comment: Yes I think so. I'm working on an example for you.

Comment: @Tejas The sunbeam node has (x,y) parameters at the top. Adjust those to move its source around the image.

Comment: @JakeD so is X the height? Or is Y the height?

Comment: @Tejas x is left/right, y is up/down (directions: +x >, -x <, +y ^, -y v). As in the Cartesian coordinate system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#/media/File:Cartesian-coordinate-system.svg Try playing with different values to get a feel for how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask was limiting the result of the sunbeam node to the doorway itself. You can multiply the mask against the image, then run that through sunbeam and add the result to the original image.

[image]